# Element not interactable in dropdown. How to get an element?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Help please to get a correct solution of my task.

I have this dropdown (it looks like dropdown) with code:

```
<div class="jcf-select-drop jcf-select-jcf-hidden jcf-unselectable"      style="position: absolute; top: 1331px; width: 376.125px; left: 285.75px;">
<div class="jcf-select-drop-content">
    <span class="jcf-list jcf-scroll-active">
        <span class="jcf-list-content" style="max-height: 369px; overflow: auto;">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="jcf-option" data-index="0">Afghanistan</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="jcf-option" data-index="218">USA</span>
                </li>
```

And simple test:

```
let countryTest = $$("span.jcf-select.jcf-unselectable").first();
let USA = $("body > div.jcf-select-drop.jcf-select-jcf-hidden.jcf-    unselectable > div > span > span > ul > li:nth-child(217) > span");

countryTest.click();
USA.click();
```

I need to select USA, but have an error "Failed: element not interactable". I can get Afghanistan, but not USA.. I tried

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(USA).click().perform();
```

but it isn't help. 
Can I somehow click on USA-element using data-index? Or what is correct way to choose the element?
And how is there a way to make shorter the element(by.css), because it's too long..

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the dropdown contains a full list of countries. As such, USA will not be high on the list (number 218 it looks like). Because your dropdown will only display a limited amount of countries at once, USA is hidden. Most dropdowns allow text to be entered to search for a country. This also limits the matches to all be displayed on the screen. You can then click on USA (although its index may have changed)
Example

```
let countryTest = $$("span.jcf-select.jcf-unselectable").first();
let USA = $("body > div.jcf-select-drop.jcf-select-jcf-hidden.jcf-unselectable > div > span > span > ul > li:nth-child(217) > span");
//keep in mind USA selector will likely have changed after you do your search

countryTest.click();
countryTest.sendKeys('USA'); //likely will be a different element that you have to send keys to
USA.click();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.
When I do: 
countryTest.sendKeys('USA'); 
I've got error with: Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: Of course, I can pass tests with the first Visible countries now, but it's just interesting for the future HOW to deal with such situation correctly?..

Comment: @EkaterinaSalazkina I should have clarified. countryTest.sendKeys(); will not send the keys to the proper element. I cannot tell from your html what is the proper element to perform sendKeys() on. When you select the dropdown does a input box show itself? That would be what you need to perform the sendkeys() on

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
const countryTest = element(by.cssContainingText('spna.jcf-list-content>ul>li>span', 'USA'));
```

So `countryTest.click()` selects USA from the dropDown.

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already solved clicking a parent element that displays the dropdown, have you tried the following?:

If you have just those 2 options:

```
var USA = element.all(by.css('.jcf-list-content ul li span')).last();

countryTest.click();
USA.click();
```

If the dropdown has more options (USA being 218?):

```
var USA = element.all(by.css('.jcf-list-content ul li span')).get(218);

countryTest.click();
USA.click();
```

You can try with the 'span' at the end, or removing it. I'm not sure which one will work.

Ultimately, try something like this:

```
var USA = element(by.cssContainingText('li', 'USA')); 

countryTest.click();
USA.click();
```

Hope it helps.